# get files from doc library is not working

Tags: 2010, development

I just dont understand, I need to move some files from one document library, to a document library in a subsite.

But the filescollection its always zero, but there are files there.

What am I missing?

```
using (SPSite oSPSite = new SPSite(SourceUrl))
                {
                    using (SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPSite.RootWeb)
                    {
                        #region Get existing website documents
                            SPFolder oFolder = oSPWeb.GetFolder(NameDocLibrary);
                            SPList docLibraryToDelete = oSPWeb.Lists[NameDocLibrary];
                            SPFileCollection collFile = oFolder.Files;

                            List<SPFile> listFiles = new List<SPFile>(collFile.Count);
                            foreach (SPFile oFile in collFile)
                            {
                                listFiles.Add(oFile);
                            }
                            Guid ID = new Guid();

                        #endregion


                        #region Move Document Library
                        using (SPSite oSPSiteArchive = new SPSite(SourceUrl))
                        {
                            using (SPWeb oSPWebArchive = oSPSite.OpenWeb("Archive"))
                            {
                                SPList newDocLibrary =oSPWebArchive.Lists.TryGetList(NameDocLibrary);
                                if (newDocLibrary == null)
                                {
                                    ID = oSPWebArchive.Lists.Add(NameDocLibrary, NameDocLibrary, SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    ID = oSPWebArchive.Lists[NameDocLibrary].ID;
                                }

                                foreach (SPFile moveFile in listFiles)
                                {
                                    moveFile.MoveTo(oSPWebArchive.Url + "/" + NameDocLibrary + "/" + moveFile.Name, true);
                                }
                                oFolder.Delete();
                                oFolder.Update();
                                docLibraryToDelete.Delete();
                                //docLibraryToDelete.Update();
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: do you have access to a debugger to use break points?

Comment: yes I always debug, there are 2 files, one gif and one png, and this line:   SPFileCollection collFile = oFolder.Files;
is always return item count to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the full address for the GetFolder function call (http://Server/Site/Library) to make sure it is pulling from the right place. I believe this particular function does not actually error on you, so you might not have successfully pulled the folder at all.

Comment: with the full url it works, with the library name only it doesnt, even if is in the context, I also changed it a little bit and i call the Spfolder.exist method first, apparently the SpFolder is never set to null, even if the parameter in the constructor is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Are the document files at the root of the document library or are they all in subfolders?

If they are all in subfolders, then getting folder object at the root of the document library will return 0 for the number of files, since it does not directly contain any files, only folders.  You will have to go into each subfolder by using the SubFolder property of the oFolder object.

Comment: the files are at the root of the document library, thats why I dont understand it